# averaging while looping, the sum won't clear and thus keeps adding numbers from previous loop entry

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main () {
 int days, flights, t, b;
 float length, mean, sum;

 printf("How many days has your dragon been practicing?\n");
 scanf("%d", &days);

 for(t=1; t<=days; t++) {
    printf("How many flights were completed in day #%d?\n", t);
    scanf("%d", &flights);
    for(b=1; b<=flights; b++) {
        printf("How long was flight #%d?\n", b);
        scanf("%f", &length);
        sum+=length;
     }
        mean = sum/flights;
        printf("Day #%d: The average distance is %.3f.\n", t, mean);

}

}
```

the sum used to calculate the mean is supposed to be only the number from one iteration of the loop added together. instead the sum used numbers from the new iteration and old iteration added together.

Comment: You should check scanf for errors.

Comment: You better be joking by doing that. Why did you just edited your all question ?

Comment: @rasoolni: When you vandalize your question it renders the answers pointless. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, after the last `printf()` statement, you should reset `sum` to 0, like `sum = 0;`.

That said, the major issue in your code is that, you're using `sum` (an automatic storage local variable) while uninitialized. You should be initializing `sum` to some value (0, maybe) before making use (`sum+=`) of it. Otherwise, it it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To quote `C11` standard, chapter §6.7.9

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. [...]

Comment: That would still make it uninitialized on the first time.

Comment: @Leeor right, missed that one Will update in a jiffy.

Comment: Another problem could be also here, where **int flights** and **float mean, sum**, which is: **conversion to ‘float’ from ‘int’ may alter its value**  =>> **mean = sum/flights;**

Comment: @SouravGhosh It doesn't meter anymore, the OP decide to change he's Question.

Answer (score 1):

sum won't clear because you don't clear it ! The point of writing code is to make your dumb machine(yeah dumb!) know when it's got to do what! 
So  immediately after

```
for(t=1;t<=days;t++)
{
```

Add this:

```
 sum=0;
```

This will ensure that your sum value is reset every day your dragon takes a flight! Otherwise C will use some random garbage value as your sum and you would receive weird answers!

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1)  If you call scanf() just after you call printf(), there is no reason to use '\n' inside that printf at the end.

2)   Always check scanf() for errors or your code is useless if errors occurs.

Now about your code:

When you use something like **x+=y** this means **x = x + y**.
So, in your case **sum+=length** means **sum=sum+length**. Do you know the value of **sum**? Yes is a garbage value.

About this line **mean = sum/flights;**, what is **mean, sum** and what is **flights**? Yes, first are **float** but second is **int**.

Now putting all together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    int days, flights, t, b;
    float length, mean, sum=0;

    printf("How many days has your dragon been practicing?: ");

    if((scanf("%d", &days)) != 1){
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    for(t=1; t<=days; t++) {
        printf("How many flights were completed in day #%d?: ", t);

        if((scanf("%d", &flights)) != 1){
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    for(b=1; b<=flights; b++) {
        printf("How long was flight #%d?\n", b);

        if((scanf("%f", &length)) != 1){
            printf("Error\n");
        }
        sum+=length;
    }

        mean = sum/(float)flights;
        printf("Day #%d: The average distance is %.3f.\n", t, mean);
    }
    return 0;
}
```